# Removing Focused Border from JavaFX Tab

Tags: css, javafx

I'm trying to style the JavaFX TabPane. I've got the styling how I want, minus this weird outline that appears around the label when the tab is focused. I included two screenshots to show what the tab looks like just after clicking it, and then again after clicking away from the application.

I want to remove the rectangular outline around the label when the tab is focused.

[image]

[image]

I have tried doing something like this, but it doesn't seem to work.

```css
.tab-pane .tab:focused {
    -fx-border-width: 0px;
    -fx-border-style: none;
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
}
```

This is the full CSS file I'm working with

```css
.tab-pane .tab-header-background {
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 2px 0;
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-border-color: primary-3;
}

.tab-pane .tab-header-area {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

.tab-pane .tab {
    -fx-padding: 10px;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-style: none;
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
}

.tab-pane .tab:hover {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-base;
}

.tab-pane .tab:selected {
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 2px 0;
    -fx-border-color: -fx-accent;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at JFoenix JFXTabPane. I think it would suit you well.
You can have a look at the css : https://github.com/sshahine/JFoenix/blob/master/jfoenix/src/main/resources/com/jfoenix/assets/css/controls/jfx-tab-pane.css